# Specifying a list of valid constructors as an argument type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have some JavaScript (simplified) like this

```
function createTypedArray(data, TypedArrayConstructor) {
  return new TypedArrayConstructor(data);
}
```

Which you can call like this

```
const f32 = createTypedArray([1, 2, 3], Float32Array);
const u8 = createTypedArray([4, 5, 6], Uint8Array);
```

How can I specify the type of `TypedArrayConstructor` this in typescript? (note: I'm not worried about the return type).

I think the best solution would mean typescript would complain if it's not actually a typedarray constructor.

```
class NotTypedArray {
  constructor(...args) {  }  // assume typed to match signature of typedarrays
}

const nta = createTypedArray([1, 2, 3], NotTypedArray); // error?
```

But that's not a requirement, mostly a nice to have. Ideally it would be typed in such a way that intellisense could suggest types that fit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [constructor signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures):

```
function createTypedArray<T>(data: number[], TypedArrayConstructor: new (dat: number[]) => T) {
  return new TypedArrayConstructor(data);
}


const f32 = createTypedArray([1, 2, 3], Float32Array);
const u8 = createTypedArray([4, 5, 6], Uint8Array);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQFQJ4AOaAJgIIooZ4A8OAfABTFYYBciYIAtgEZooBtALoAaRPiJkKVAMIIAzlBQhocFOzBoA7oiZYN3PoKEBKRAF464swG8AUIkTooIFEk06JJcpTxywisqqKHpQGCYA3HYAvnZxEApQiMAAzABMFsjoWLiE3tJ4DAIAjGJpYimiiABiADZwWOk+VJF2CQFJIAAcmaiY2F5SvkUALGIArGIAbFUAqjBgUF3NeK1AA)

I also added a generic type parameter for a correct return type

Comment: Thanks! That works. Though it doens't reject invalid constructors. For example `bad = createTypedArray([1, 2, 3], Array);` nor does it suggest correct types. The question said those weren't required but if there is a solution that guides the user that would arguably be better.

Comment: @samanthaj `new Array([1,2,3])` is valid. It will reject constrcutors that take other types as parameters https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQFQJ4AOaAJgIIooZ4A8OAfABTFYYBciYIAtgEZooBtALoAaRPiJkKVAMIIAzlBQhocFOzBoA7oiZYN3PoKEBKRAF464swG8AUIkTooIFEk06JJcpTxywisqqKHpQGCYA3HYAvnZxEApQiMAAzABMFsjoWLiE3tJ4DAIAjGJpYimiiABiADZwWOk+VJF2CQFJIAAcmaiY2F5SvkUALGIArGIAbFUAqjBgUF3NeK3tiogAHr3ZA3lDVEWliOWIlWIrrW21GPLy4mgb9o7rSipQagzYiuyBCwDmtgcjkQwNisT6OUGKyOIlO5weihMQA . You can constraint the return type of the ctor to be something that can be iterable which typed arrays are.

Comment: Array is not valid for my needs. If the user passes in Array, the code using this function will crash because Array is not TypedArray. I'd be nice if that was rejected. Simialrly, it'd be nice if when the user types `createTypedArray(someArray, ` that auto-completors would only provide thigns that are or return a typedarray constructor. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

This works for my needs

```
type TypedArrayConstructor = 
   Int8ArrayConstructor | 
   Uint8ArrayConstructor | 
   Uint8ClampedArrayConstructor |
   Int16ArrayConstructor | 
   Uint16ArrayConstructor | 
   Int32ArrayConstructor | 
   Uint32ArrayConstructor | 
   Float32ArrayConstructor |
   Float64ArrayConstructor ;

function createTypedArray(data: number[], TypedArrayConstructor: TypedArrayConstructor) {
  return new TypedArrayConstructor(data);
}

const f32 = createTypedArray([1, 2, 3], Float32Array);
const u8 = createTypedArray([4, 5, 6], Uint8Array);
const a = createTypedArray([4, 5, 6], Array);  // error! (yay!)
```

I didn't know the constructors for typedarrays were predefined

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEBMCCAnFBDEBhA9gOwGdgUBXAY2BxSgF4oAoKJgST2AA5UNt8jSKqUAD4MmUAKoBLNpzSZchYuUrURjJlJlYANugC2kZHJ6L+K4eqitgARgBsXebyUDVojdNsPjCvssFqYtYAzABMjiZ+rsLuEp5hEb4u5oFMAGLaOOjACT7OZgGWGVnAdgAsifn+1ADc9PQAZiR4FJL4UGQoENkQcIYRABQI2egAXFB4JHoARhAoANoAugA0sPBG3EkFKON9iJWm1QCUUADe6l3AJCh4ExAA7mv9eYeuQyNHdQC+9WTOUA0wrQOl0ensNpgBvMbKtQqtgisoMVsrluJ96H9FFASOxgZ1usBeutBvMyqsAKyrOyIzQcCLozFEKDoPGgwngklkqCUqDU1b0mpMAD0QqgcxQVAAhFABiBMJKjvQgA)